# Updating one field per row, 1 million + rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large address database I need to "clean up".

Example, the address contains the county but not always in the same field, sometimes its in address3 and sometimes address4 or not at all.

I've put everything in a table, created a new field called County and the php loads the data (1000 rows at a time for testing) into an array.

It searches for "CO." in address3 or 4 and if found then copies the contents of that cell to "County". So far so good.

The problem is that it runs extremely slow, I use the following as the UPDATE:

$update = "UPDATE opportunities SET County='" . $address4 . "' " . "WHERE id=" . $id;

Is there a faster way to do this than running the above line for each entry?

Comment: Try using a prepared statement. (What do you mean by "slow"?)

Comment: if 'id' is indexed it should be pretty fast.

Comment: Not if there are specific things that you need to do to each record individually.  If the data is simply wrong and not "wrong" for each (or many) records, then you can't expect a computer to know how to clean the data up without giving it some login to adhere to.  If you didn't specify `WHERE id=...` then you can easily run similar commands over the breath of the whole data set within your table.

Comment: try adding an index to `id`.

Comment: Or you do the whole thing in one query: `UPDATE opp SET county=IF(substring(address3,1,3)='CO.',address3,address4)`

Answer (score 5):

It would be faster to do it directly in SQL, but by its nature this sort of string searching will be pretty slow:

```sql
UPDATE opportunities
SET    County = CASE
         WHEN address3 LIKE '%CO.%' THEN address3
         WHEN address4 LIKE '%CO.%' THEN address4
       END
```

Comment: It is easier to do this in SQL directly by executing queries, UNLESS your code provides you with a simple interface that can aid you to make your changes with more accuracy.

Comment: Excellent, hadn't thought of doing it in SQL directly - mostly coz' the hard bit is next - how to find the town name and put it in a field called "Town". At least with county they are always preceeded by "CO." - not so for Town. Thanks!

Comment: @user1517428: If they're always *preceeded* by "CO.", then you should remove the leading `%` from the above patterns - it will make a significant difference to the performance of this query.